# what's the best tool to create a Product Catalog in Ubuntu?

Tags: presentation

i'm going to create a Catalog for one of our proposals... as i've recently migrated to Ubuntu, i don't know tools to do such a job. In windows i might do this with **MS PowerPoint** or **Adobe InDesign**. here i just know **OpenOffice Presentation**.

I wanna create a **simple** and **official** catalog. and i want to have a wast range of available **free templates** to choose among.

what's the best tool to create a **fast**, **well-looking** PDF catalog?

Answer (score 6):

## Scribus

[Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/) is an Open Source program that brings award-winning professional page layout to Linux/UNIX, Mac OS X, OS/2 Warp 4/eComStation and Windows desktops with a combination of "press-ready" output and new approaches to page layout. 
Underneath the modern and user friendly interface, Scribus supports professional publishing features, such as CMYK color, separations, Spot Colors, ICC color management and versatile PDF creation.

Why would you want to use Scribus? Scribus is powerful software that helps you create great looking documents of all kinds. It also comes with a lot of support options to help you achieve the best result. There is an enthusiastic and friendly community around Scribus that assists beginner and pro alike through our mailing list, IRC channel, wiki, contracted support, and the bugtracker.

Comment: so you are a guy of Scribus! i just watched it's name in ubuntustudio packages... so, how is Scibus in free templates? is there any resource for choosing a template or it's own templates (www.scribus.net/?q=node/122) covers any need?

Comment: The templates available in package `scribus-templates` (and on the site) are pretty few, sadly.

Comment: oh, ready-to-use templates is important to make the catalog fast.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wiki made ​​by the Documentation Team Brazil - http://wiki.ubuntu-br.org/DTPnoUbuntu